How do I enable Emmet Abbreviation in CodeSandbox.io?

Normally, when typing "div", there should be a recommendation from Emmet Abbreviation popping beside it, same with the other HTML elements, but there isn't. How can I fix this?
I tried going to Editor -> User Preferences
then in the search box, I typed "Javascript Autoclosing Tags"
but it didn't gave me any result.
P.S. this problem also occurs in JSX

Make sure your language mode is set correctly and that your file extension is '.jsx'.
When you type 'div', press Tab to activate the completions. Alternatively, you can manually trigger it by typing 'div' and then pressing Ctrl + E (on Windows) or Cmd + E (on Mac).
I've also found that sometimes other browser extensions can interfere with your CodeSandbox environment. To avoid this, try disabling any extensions, refreshing your browser, or running it in incognito mode.
